# --extra-index-url not work in python requirements.txt

Tags: python, ubuntu, pypi

I try to download this package:

```
echo --extra-index-url https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/ pycoral~=2.0 >requirements.txt
cat /root/requirements.txt
```

Here is the output:

```
--extra-index-url https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/ pycoral~=2.0
```

Then download:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/test
pip3 download --requirement /root/requirements.txt --dest /tmp/test
```

Here is the output:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/dhcrypto.py:15: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/secretstorage/util.py:19: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: int_from_bytes is deprecated, use int.from_bytes instead
  from cryptography.utils import int_from_bytes
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/
```

Then list the directory:

```
ls -alith /tmp/test

total 8.0K
57409537 drwxrwxrwt 22 root root 4.0K Apr 27 15:48 ..
57409566 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Apr 27 15:48 .
```

The `pip3` can't download the package as expected. How to download with `requirements.txt` for this `non github package`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requirements.txt` should probably look like this:

```
--extra-index-url https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/

pycoral~=2.0
```

In the `requirements.txt` file format specification, the `--extra-index-url` option is considered a "global option" and has to be isolated on its own line:

> The following options have an effect on the entire pip install run, and must be specified on their individual lines.
>
> - --extra-index-url
> - [...]

-- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#global-options